# "The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception" on Android in unity 2022.3.11

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am building an app using unity2022.3.11.
The error
"The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception"
is occurring in this code when launching on an Android device after build.

```
await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
```

1. What is the cause of this error?
2. Is this due to build or is there something I should add from firebase unitypackage?
3. If it cause of build, how do I configure gradle?

Resolve was done with the Android resolver in the External dependency manager.

Placed them in Assets/Plugins/Android.

```
baseProjectTemplate.gradle
gradleTemplate.properties
mainTemplate.gradle
settingTemplate.gradle
```

Filled in gradleTemplate.properties.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this, this functions should not be awaited as shown below
(This is an example of a FirebaseInit script I wrote)

```
void Start()
{
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {

        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
            FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventLogin);
            Debug.Log("The Firebase Is INIT and is tracking");

            FetchDataAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
        }
```

I hope this will help you with resolving your error

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I'm trying to see if I can solve another problem that "can't build first" and I'll try when that is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by TheCoderEll, typically you should not await `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync`.

The easiest/ most straightforward way is to use [ContinueWithOnMainThread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) as shown in [Firebase's Level up With Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/4ed69c9af9341bb38cc02ea01c3ce9c3f0ccb25f/Assets/Hamster/Scripts/MainGame.cs#L177):

```cs
using Firebase.Extensions;

//...

    private void InitializeFirebaseAndStartGame()
    {
      Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(
        previousTask => 
        {
          var dependencyStatus = previousTask.Result;
          if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
            // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
            app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            // Begin/perform all downstream/Firebase dependent functionality from here
          } else {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(
              $"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {dependencyStatus}\n" +
              "Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here");
          }
        });
    }
```

As for your build errors consult the following: Debugging the [Game Build, Install and Run Process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide) and [EDM4U Usage Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/troubleshooting-faq.md)